# Why do I keep getting 'No module named 'pywintypes'' whenever I try to import win32com.client or pywin32?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, ms-word, docx

Here is my code. I am trying to use  docx2pdf to convert pdf files to docx.

```
import win32com.client
#from win32 import _win32sysloader
#from win32 import win32api
#from docx2pdf import convert

def translator():

    print('reconverting')
    convert("C:\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\btab083 (1).docx", "C:\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\btab083 (1).pdf")
    print('success')

translator()
```

I'm using Python 3.11.4

As you can see I tried different import statements of(commented out) as solutions. I found them online. No matter what order I tried them I kept getting `No module named 'pywintypes'` or `No module named '_win32sysloader'`.

I installed pywin32 using '`pip install pywin32`. I also used `python pywin32_postinstall.py -install`, `pip install win32`, `python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install` and `python -m pip install --upgrade pywin32`.

I also tried pip install pywintypes